# Alternative ways to switch between applications if cmd+tab doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, macos, application-switcher

What are alternative ways to switch between applications?

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work for me in some games. For example on steam; "Crusader Kings II", "The Talos Principle".

So i have no ability to switch to another application like Safari when needed unless I quit the game. This is very inconvenient.

I also tried <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd>  and  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>H</kbd>, they do not work either.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Esc</kbd> force quits the game immediately.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work because the game is running  in **Full Screen**.

In most games you can enable *Window Mode* within the game's *Preferences* and / or switch between *Window Mode* and *Full Screen* with a shortcut.

As for my experience, doing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> tends to do the trick.

Comment: Cmd+Tab works in most of applications (and games), that run Full Screen. But thank you for the tip.

Comment: Cmd+M also doesn't work for me.

Comment: @klm123 No luck with the *Preferences*, either?

Comment: Some luck, I can play with borderless window, but menu bar makes it hard. And this is not what I want, since not all application have window mode.